# Ms Access Run-time error 2147217805(80040e73) Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification

Tags: ms-access

As said in the title, I have the connection issue with the following code:

```
Set xl = New Excel.Application
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset                        
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fileName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';"
```

I am trying to import data from a "*.xls" file to my Access table while have some edit on the raw data before input.

I guess it is the cn.Open part triggered the error, but not sure which part I should change to fix it.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Share the filename, there's probably stuff in there that's not allowed.

Comment: fileName = "P:\**Folder**\**Folder**\" & fileNumber & "-" & UploadDate & "Upload.xls" (fileNumber is a five digits number and UploadDate is a date as its name)

Comment: ... Just give me the _specific_ file name causing the error, including the _actual_ folder names, what you've currently shared tells me absolutely nothing

Comment: fileName = "P:\FTP\Regular Upload Report\" & fileNumber & "-" & RglUploadDate & "RegularUpload.xls"  P is a share drive. one of the fileNumber is 32159, RglUploadDate would be in format as 20190116 as of today.

Comment: Hmmm... Try using double double quotes instead of single ones: `cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"`

Comment: Seems like double double quotes works!! I have not written following code yet, but no error message pops up now!! Thanks a lot!!! PS. May I ask the reason why double double quotes work?

Comment: I've added an answer with some further explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double double quotes to delimit strings in the OLEDB connection string:

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"
```

Just like in VBA, OLEDB requires strings to be delimited by double quotes, not single quotes.

Because double quotes are string delimiters in VBA, you need to double up the double quotes to escape them.